# Hadoop job chaining: Keep track of the job index

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm chaining jobs together. The output of the reduce at round `i` is a file needed in the `Mapper` `setup()` of round `i+1`. I'm trying to get the name of this file in the `reduce`. What's a good way to access the index of the job? Perhaps giving the job the name `i` and accessing that name in the `reduce`?

**UPDATE** For each job, I need to report a value which is a summary statistic of each job that I compute in `reduce` (I have one reducer). How can I output that value into its own file, or append to a single file? My output path is already used for the main computation.

I ended up appending the summary statistic to a file in HDFS in the `cleanup` of each reducer, and I had only one reducer per job.

```
@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
    FSDataOutputStream os = hdfs.append(new Path(COST_FILENAME));
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(os);
    out.println(String.valueOf(cost));
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution would be to use different input/output folders for the jobs using `Job#setInputPath()` and `Job#setOutputPath()`.

- job1: input: `input`, output: `output-1`
- job2: input: `output-1`, output: `output-2`
- ...
- jobN: input: `output-(N-1)`, output: `output-N`